# Thermodynamics: Are pressure and temperature enough to calculate enthalpy?

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation, condensation

[image]

From the chart above, it looks like it is possible to calculate enthalpy from just pressure and temperature.  After a few hours of Googling my question, I'm not able to find anything helpful.

My company is interested in finding the effectiveness of an air conditioning system by measuring the change in enthalpy from one side to the other.  As a software person, I need a formula that I can use to calculate the enthalpy.  I know this formula would need to include different properties of the gas, can you elaborate on what those constants are?  Thank you very much.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy#Other_expressions suggests $\mathrm{d}H = C_p\mathrm{d}T+V(1-\alpha T)\mathrm{d}p$ with $\alpha$ being the coefficient of (cubic) thermal expansion of the gas: $\alpha=\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p$. So in addition to $P$ and $T$, you'd need to know $V$ (which could be a known function of $P$ and $T$ depending on your assumptions) and some constants for your gas which can probably be found in a table somewhere.

Comment: To shoot down your idea ASAP: point 4 is a saturated mix (I believe).  The pressure and temperature are not sufficient to calculate the enthalpy of a saturated mix.  So your answer is "no".

Comment: @AlanSE, In vapor-compression cycle (per the graph), enthalpy of point 4 is commonly estimated by assuming it's equal to that of point 3. Point 3 is saturated liquid and it's usually "expanded" through a valve which is modeled as a throttling process.

Answer (score 2):

The formula that you are looking for is
$$H=H_0+
\int_0^\rho \frac{[P-T(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T})_{\rho}]}{\rho^2} d\rho + 
\frac{P}{\rho} -
RT + 
\frac52R(T-T_0)
$$
But this is useless to you unless you know the equation of state of your substance (if you have vapor and liquid, it is not $Pv=RT$) and the reference value $H_0$ which is attained at $T_0$. In the formula above $T$ is temperature, $P$ is pressure, $\rho$ is density (the equation of state is a relationship among these three parameters, so only two of them are independent) and $R$ is 8.31 J/mol K - the universal gas constant.

Pressure and temperature are sufficient to compute any state variable, including enthalpy, *provided* you have a single chemical component (for example pure water, or pure nitrogen, or pure gold) and a single phase (gas only or liquid only or solid only, i.e. no boiling, melting, etc.) system. Moreover, for ideal gas (the kind where $Pv=RT$) temperature alone determines enthalpy (in the formula above all the terms with $P$ in them will drop out in this case), i.e. $H$ is pressure-independent. But if you have more than one component or more than one phase (the case in the diagram shown), you need to specify chemical and/or phase make-up of your system to fix the thermodynamics.

Comment: Hey Ted, you can render all of that $\TeX$ inline. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

This is a refrigeration thermodynamic question (I say this if you wish to further look information in the web/books). It's been some years since I dealt with HVAC. But taking my trusty "Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics" by Moran & Shapiro book (good reference if you're going to do this kind of stuff for a while), I'll try to shed some light. But I suggest you get a copy of a thermo book if this is going to be for a job - it's more thorough than what I'm going to write.

If you are dealing with a vapor-compression cycle (which most likely it is since this is the common air conditioning sytem), the coefficient of performance of a vapor-compression refrigeration cycle is:
$$\beta = \frac{h_1-h_4}{h_2-h_1}$$

If you are dealing with a gas refrigeration system (this is used to reach very low temperatures and specialized applications such as aircraft cooling), the coefficient of performance of the Brayton refrigeration cycle is:
$$\beta = \frac{h_1-h_4}{(h_2-h_1)-(h_3-h_4)}$$

Where $h_n$ is enthalpy at point $n$. Be careful of the location for $n$, it might change depending the source. In this case, I'm using your locations for $n$. The coefficient of performance is:
$$\beta = Q_{in}/W_{cycle}$$

Where (for a refrigeration & heat pump cycle):

$$W_{cycle} = Q_{out} - Q_{in}$$

Where "$Q_{in}$ is the energy transferred by heat *into* the system undergoing the cycle *from* the cold body, and $Q_{out}$ is the energy discharged by heat transfer *from* the system *to* the hot body." Moran & Shapiro

**How to calculate enthalpy values:** These values are available for the different commercially available refrigerants. If you know your refrigerant, try a web search for them or if not send a email/call to a supplier. And yes you only need pressure and temperature. They are usually found either by tables, or Pressure-Enthalpy diagrams (which look very scary for the untrained eye, but you get a hold of them pretty quickly):
http://www2.dupont.com/Refrigerants/en_US/assets/downloads/h47122_SuvaHP_push.pdf

**To answer your question directly:**
The "effectiveness of an air conditioning system" is usually measured by the coefficient of performance. And yes, it can be calculated by using just enthalpy values. But with all four values of the refrigeration cycle, not just two like I think you are asking.

**Values you need for making a calculations**:
Most likely, you don't have the pressure and temperature of all points in the diagram. If you assume *ideal vapor-compression refrigeration cycle*, you only need:

1. Temperature of "Cold Region (place you're keeping cool)" and "Warm Region (place you're transferring the heat to)"
2. Temperature of saturated [refrigerant] vapor that enters the compressor
3. Temperature of saturated [refrigerant] liquid leaving the condenser
4. Refrigerant type

In the Moran & Shapiro book there are examples how to do this, and also with modifications for when there are irreversible heat transfer effects and for "actual" vapor-compression cycles. If you don't find any online, maybe I'll add the examples when I have some more free time.

Answer (score 0):

This website from NIST: http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/fluid/ will give you any thermodynamic property you want for any temperature and pressure, for a range of fluids including Ethane, 1,1,1,2-tetrafluoro- (R134a).  It will even plot a graph if you like.

If you want to put this in software you can buy the NIST Reference Fluid Thermodynamic and Transport Properties Database (REFPROP) code from NIST http://www.nist.gov/srd/nist23.cfm.